# Why am I getting two different formats from Automator Workflow Get Variable Value

Tags: applescript, automator, python

I have an Automator Workflow that runs an AppleScript where the operator chooses one of three option from a list {"Move Staff", "Move Retouch", "Move Grade"}

A Set Value of Variable sets Variable: StaffOrRetouch

A second AppleScript checks the input value and when it is "Move Grade" sets selectedValue to choose from from list {"1", "2", "3"}
otherwise it sets selectedValue to input

Another Set Value of Variable sets Variable StaffOrRetouch

(2) Ask for Finder Items are run

Get Value of Variable StaffOrRetouch shows the following:
When the selected item is "Move Retouch"  The results of the Workflow step Get Value of Variable:StaffOrRetouch shows

/Users/John/Desktop/_03 Input LAB FILE.tsv

/Users/John/Desktop/_03 Control Testing 60 jpg files

Move Retouch

However when the selected item is "Move Grade" The results of the Workflow step Get Value of Variable:GradeOrRetouch shows
(
"/Users/John/Desktop/_03 Input LAB FILE.tsv",

"/Users/John/Desktop/_03 Control Testing 60 jpg files",

"(
2
)"
)

This second format causes errors in the next step which is a python script.

Here's the testing python script: Input: as arguments

```
/usr/bin/python3 <<'EOF' - "${@}"

import sys
import os
import csv
import shutil

file_containing_list = sys.argv[1]
copy_from_folder = sys.argv[2]
proc_type = sys.argv[3]


print(file_containing_list)
print(copy_from_folder)
print(proc_type)


EOF
```

Comment: The value of the `StaffOrRetouch` variable is being passed on to the Python script in either case - what are you expecting?

Comment: The first runs ok the second errors out with The action “Run Shell Script” encountered an error: “-[__NSArrayM fileSystemRepresentation]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x600001850a20”

Comment: With two different formats being passed I don't know how to identify format is passed and I don't know how to handle the second format.

Comment: The third argument is whatever your AppleScripts are returning.  The originally posted script(s) run, so something like "unrecognized selector" indicates that more detail is needed to figure out what is going on.  Consider editing your question to include an [MVCE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) (or at least the parts that are giving the errors), along with some information about whatever it is you are trying to do.

Comment: I rebuilt the Automator Workflow from scratch and it works fine. Not sure what the problem was.